# Running sql against external Redshift database from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, amazon-redshift

Is there a good way to execute SQL against an arbitrary Redshift database from Rails?

The various adapter gems I have found all seem fairly unmaintained:

https://github.com/remind101/sequel-redshift

https://github.com/aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter

https://github.com/fiksu/activerecord-redshift-adapter

I just want to connect to a Redshift db with some arbitrary host/username/password, then run some SQL against it.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift presents itself as PostgreSQL. Therefore, any JDBC/ODBC driver that can connect with PostreSQL will work with Redshift.

Additional drivers specific to Redshift have also been released, see:

- [Custom ODBC/JDBC Drivers and Query Visualization for Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/custom-odbcjdbc-drivers-and-query-visualization-for-amazon-redshift/)